# How can I retrieve referenced tables (FKs) using PHP from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship

Using SHOW TABLE and SHOW  COLUMNS , I can get info about tables (fields, if they are PRIMARY KEYS, FK, etc...) but NOTHING about outlinks of foreign keys!

EDIT: Thanks a lot... I will have the reference

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/key-column-usage-table.html

at information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME  (links to)  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `information_schema.key_column_usage` table:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
```

If you need to limit your query to a particular database, you can add `AND table_schema = 'yourdatabase'`.

Comment: Many thanks webbi,... I see also it's possible using SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name

Comment: Yes, you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` but you'll have to parse the SQL yourself if you want to then use the tables/columns in your code.